# How to re-run ./configure with the same parameters?

Tags: compilation, configure, autoconf, automake

A few months ago I installed an application from source by executing

```
./configure --whatever
make
sudo make install
```

I reinstalled my OS recently and now I would like to install this application again, but I don't remember what compile flags I used back then. However, since I kept all files from my home, I still have the source code and my original build. Is there a way to recover the ./configure parameters I used originally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just re-run `make`? after all, i think you are mainly after re-running the *installation* phase rather than the *configure*-step.

however, to specifically answer your question: autotools record your configure-invocation in the `config.status` file.
you can call it to re-run your configure phase "in the same conditions":

```
./config.status --recheck
```

(this is mainly needed internally by autotools: if you hack your Makefile.am or your configure.ac, automake will rebuild the build-system so the changes have an effect; in order to do this correctly, it must invoke configure in the same way as it was originally called (by the user))

Comment: Regarding your initial suggestion of just re-running make: Since I installed a new OS, the exact set of installed libraries (potentially including their location and/or version numbers) have changed. I need to run ./configure again to pick up these changes and/or tell me what build dependencies are missing.

Comment: Yesterday I gave up on recovering the config I used earlier and went through the various `--enable` options again to select the ones I needed. So now I have a freshly configured and built ffmpeg, but there is no `./config.status` file. On the other hand, I found my config options in `ffbuild/config.fate` and in `ffbuild/config.mak`. :)

Comment: [contd] By doing so I realized that this `./configure` script was not generated by `autoconf`, so I mistagged my question. Although your answer doesn't apply in my situation, I'll upvote and accept it because it _does_ answer the question that I _actually_ asked. :)